# Using Entity Framework Core in a Powershell Cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell, entity-framework-core, powershell-cmdlet

Is it possible to build a PowerShell cmdlet that incorporate Entity Framework (Core or EF6) for access to an SQL Server database?

I've been writing cmdlets in C# for years, but I've gone through a nightmare the last coupla days trying to use Entity Framework in a project due to what appear to be assembly version clashes.

Project has three libraries:

- `MyProject.Commands.dll` - cmdlets to load
- `MyProject.Lib.dll` - common library code used by the cmdlets
- `MyProject.EF.dll` - the Entity Framework stuff only.

EF is separate because I use a database-first approach (I have to reverse engineer an existing system), so the various `.cs` model files built from the database are in a separate unit just so keep them straight.

I'm building all this on Windows 10, and the project only needs to run on *this machine*. It's talking to an SQL Database in the Azure cloud.

## First try: VS 2017 / .Net Framework 4.7.1

After using nuget to add the required packages, everything built fine, but using `Import-Module` on `MyProject.Commands.dll` gets me:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly \
   'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' \
   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After turning on some kind of binding debug logging,

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
```

I've never been able to find that exact version of `System.ComponentModel.Annotation`, but the interwebs are full of reports of this same issue.  I tried all kinds of things with the AssemblyResolver in the DLL, different versions of various frameworks, ultimately got nowhere.

Eventually I found this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/platforms/ that suggests that EF Core 3.x is not supported on any .NET framework version (on .NET Core), but this blog post from a few days ago https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-1-and-entity-framework-6-4/ suggests that it's now supported after all.

The above is a rough retelling because it's from a loooong time ago (late last night) before I went to plan B. This was maddening.

## Plan B: EF Core on .NET Core 3.1

Deciding that EF Core is likely a better direction for the future anyway, I got VS 2019 and re-targeted my entire project to EF Core 3.1 on .NET Core 3.1. This is my first foray into .NET Core.

It took a little while to get dependencies sorted out (including swapping out `System.Management.Automation` for `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`), but eventually it all built. After installing Powershell 6, I'm now greeted with:

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'D:\Dev\MyProject\MyProject.Commands\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.Commands.dll'.
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f
7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**Awesome!!**

Now it's not able to find version 4.2.2.0 of `System.Runtime`, and I'm really at a loss.

Inside each project's build area `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\` directory is a `*.deps.json` file that lists all kinds of dependencies, but every single reference to `System.Runtime` is for ver 4.3.0.

I've tried Process Monitor, various tools for looking at assemblies, poking around the GAC. Nuffin.

## Making it an App

Leaving the libraries unchanged, I encapsulated the main logic into a console application and compiled it down to a `.EXE`.

It worked the first time.

## Is this even possible?

The fact that building the console app worked so smoothly suggests that trying to make all this work in PowerShell may well be unsolvable.

A standalone app is in control of its own dependencies, but building DLLs that have to host inside another program (powershell) means we have to work and play well with *its* dependencies.

It strikes me that it *might* be possible to carefully analyze the existing `pwsh.exe` (that's Powershell 6) and find its exact set of dependencies, then look for a version of EF Core that just happens to match that set. This does not seem promising, but would likely be brittle.

As a data point, a previous version of this code worked fine when talking to the SQL server via direct SQL calls, so all the database-access baggage wasn't enough to break cmdlet compat. But adding EF core seems to.

I hate my life. Am I doomed?

**EDIT** Just to be clear, I'm not trying to use Entity Framework in a PowerShell *script*, I'm not sure I'd even want to. It's using EF in a C# DLL that does all the heavy lifting of talking to the database programatically

I already have fairly reasonable direct SQL calls (again, in C#) that works pretty well, but I have dozens of tables to reverse engineer, and it's amazingly helpful to have EF do this for me by building the models and all the easy-access code.

```
    foreach (var item in DbContext.Employee
             .Where(x => x.Salary > 1000.00)
             .OrderBy(x => x.EmployeeId))
    {
       do something
    }
```

The Entity Framework package built the `Employee` class from the definition in the database (though you can also use code-first approaches), and the above is literally the only code I had to write.

I've wanted to use EF in a PowerShell cmdlet for a long time but have never been able to make it work.

A nice drive-by read on Entity Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

**EDIT** This evening I found that I had been building my code for .NET Core rather than .NET Standard (which is yet again different from the original .NET Framework), and that explains much of why things were not loading properly.

.NET Core seems to be a portable subset, and I just got lost in the weeds from things that I didn't know were different. Also: "Core" seems to be overloaded (e.g. "Entity Framework Core" can run just fine on ".Net Standard"). Ugh.

I still haven't been able to get this to all work and play well as a cmdlet, but on the plus side I did manage to burn a few more hours.

Likely there's no good solution to this.

**EDIT** (6/2020) I found out this morning that the assembly binding logging I turned on six months ago was filling up my hard drive in the `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE` directory with *gigabytes* of HTM files. Oops.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) includes instructions on how to enable/disable this via the registry.

Comment: You are taking the hard approach.  Power Shell uses the command line utility sqlcmd.exe which you can dowload from msdn.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15  You can built a bat file or use the c# Process class to run sqlcmd.exe from inside c# project.

Comment: Wow, no.  If I wanted to just regular SQL, I that was working fine for me already.

Entity Framework is *dramatically* easier to interact with a database, especially for two-way operations (fetch some data, update some data), and outsourcing this to batch files would be a huge step backwards.

Comment: Anecdotally, I’ve seen similar issues with trying to Add-Type some nuget packages in powershell scripts. The paths that Fusion Binding scans are relative to powershell.exe so it can’t always find the dependencies, and I’ve had to manually “Add-Type” the whole tree myself from the bottom up. By contrast, the binding path search in a console app is relative to the console .exe, and it will find the dependent assemblies in the \bin folder automatically. You could try Add-Type on your Annotations dll before loading your class library...

Comment: SQLCMD is much more efficient than using SQL Client.  SQLCMD is designed for archiving large databases and queries that were taking over 30 minutes to run using SQL Client ran in a couple of minutes.  I usually use the CSV option with SQLCMD to interact with the database.  AS I said you can use the net library Process to run the command line utility.

Comment: have you ever found a workaround for that issue?
without creating a exe and import the class library direct?

Comment: @Luca - No. There are just too many conflicting dependencies, where EF has one chain of assembly+version requirements, some of which explicitly conflict with the assembly+version requirements of Powershell.

My feeling is it might be possible to work around this in narrow circumstances by doing unsupported things, but it will break during updates. It's terribly disappointing.  I ended up just doing a standard .exe that works fine.

And all those people suggesting `sqlcmd` are clearly misunderstanding the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I did some experimenting with this and actually got it to work in Powershell 7, however I couldn't get it to work with Powershell Classes as a code-first approach as powershell classes get created in a way that doesn't gel with dbset. DB-first did work however.

Comment: Have you an example of how to import the required EF dll's using PowerShell 7?

Comment: Please provide more explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is just a limitation of using dlls in powershell. Dependency importing from dlls has never worked well.

If you search long enough you will come across some solutions like people writing code to dependency walk through many layers of dlls importing each one in a loop until they are all imported. Honestly just compiling and calling a exe seems far neater and supportable to me.

We frequently do DB-First scaffolding using EF, We also had the challenge of delivering reverse engineered applications and code in a supportable manor to clients. In the end we accepted that the cleanest way was to use EF Core+.Net Core based MVC Web projects in docker containers. They are cross platform and are just 1 language neatly packaged up.

To answer your question simply, Yes the moment any of us started writing code we became doomed for all eternity.