# Creating Azure blob containers from a powershell cmdlet fails

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a small bit of C# code that creates an Azure Blob container just fine when run via a console-mode executable, but fails when the same code is part of a PowerShell cmdlet (also in C#). The failure mode is really odd: it creates the container, but then keeps retrying for a coupla minutes before it errors out. I don't get it.

The code, which is built in Visual Studio using .NET Framework 4.8, and Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.4.1:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace BlobTest.Commands
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Initialize, "AzContainer")]
    public class Initialize_AzContainer : Cmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            base.ProcessRecord();

            const string AzStorageAccount = "stevestorageaccount";
            const string AzAccessKey = "*****==";

            string connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http" // http intentional: for wireshark
                                      + $";AccountName={AzStorageAccount}"
                                      + $";AccountKey={AzAccessKey}"
                                      + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

            const string containerName = "my-test-container-2";

            var bsclient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

            WriteVerbose($"Creating container {containerName}");
            var rc = bsclient.CreateBlobContainer(containerName, PublicAccessType.None);

            WriteVerbose($"Result = {rc}");
        }
    }
}
```

This hangs for a coupla minutes before barfing:

```
PS> Import-Module .\BlobTest.Commands.dll
PS> Initialize-AzContainer -Verbose
VERBOSE: Creating container my-test-container-2

[hung out for 7 minutes]

Initialize-AzContainer : Retry failed after 6 tries.
At line:1 char:1
+ Initialize-AzContainer -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Initialize-AzContainer], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.AggregateException,BlobTest.Commands.Initialize_AzContainer
```

I intentionally use insecure http while troubleshooting so I can sniff the conversation, and Wireshark shows really odd behavior. The `//` in the traces are my notes, not part of the trace:

```
// MY END SENDS: this looks normal
PUT /my-test-container-2?restype=container HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2019-07-07
x-ms-client-request-id: acc4991b-33ab-4764-9f20-a33edb5cc4a3
x-ms-return-client-request-id: true
User-Agent: azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.4.1 (.NET Framework 4.8.4150.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363 )
x-ms-date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 17:42:27 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey <secret key info>
Host: stevestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 0

// AZURE REPLIES: all ok!
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Length: 0
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 17:42:28 GMT
ETag: "0x8D7EC64AF7BD68A"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 5ebb740e-201e-001a-354d-1e15bd000000
x-ms-client-request-id: acc4991b-33ab-4764-9f20-a33edb5cc4a3
x-ms-version: 2019-07-07
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 17:42:27 GMT

// MY END TRIES AGAIN - huh?
PUT /my-test-container-2?restype=container HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2019-07-07
x-ms-client-request-id: acc4991b-33ab-4764-9f20-a33edb5cc4a3
x-ms-return-client-request-id: true
User-Agent: azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.4.1 (.NET Framework 4.8.4150.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363 )
x-ms-date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 17:42:29 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey <secret key info>
Host: stevestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 0

// AZURE REPLIES: sorry already exists
HTTP/1.1 409 The specified container already exists.
Content-Length: 230
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 5ebb7805-201e-001a-224d-1e15bd000000
x-ms-client-request-id: acc4991b-33ab-4764-9f20-a33edb5cc4a3
x-ms-version: 2019-07-07
x-ms-error-code: ContainerAlreadyExists
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 17:42:29 GMT
...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>ContainerAlreadyExists</Code>
<Message>The specified container already exists.
RequestId:5ebb7805-201e-001a-224d-1e15bd000000
Time:2020-04-29T17:42:29.6128339Z</Message></Error>

(repeats a few times)
```

The same code works fine in a console-mode executable, and it behaves the same way whether I use `async` or regular synchronous as above. I've tried various other combinations, adding a cancellation token, etc. and nothing impacts this.

Note: I know how to create a container with the native Azure cmdlets, but the above is part of additional processing, so I'm trying to get to the bottom of the failure, not find some other way to create a container.

I've spent quite a few hours at this, and am at a loss to see what's going on.

**Edit:** I've tried rebooting my system, no difference, and this is all with PowerShell 5.1.18362.752 on Windows 10 with all latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `retry policy` is triggered here. But the weird thing is that in a console project, it does not retry if operation is successful.

As a workaround, in your code, you can set the retry policy, sample code like below:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsData.Initialize, "AzContainer")]
public class Initialize_AzContainer : Cmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        base.ProcessRecord();

       //other code

       //set the retry policy here
        var options = new BlobClientOptions();
        options.Retry.MaxRetries = 0;

        var bsclient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString, options);

        WriteVerbose($"Creating container {containerName}");

        var rc = bsclient.CreateBlobContainer(containerName, PublicAccessType.None);
        WriteVerbose($"Result = {rc}");


    }

}
```

Comment: This, unsurprisingly, didn't help; setting Retries to a lower number just makes it fail more quickly, and setting to zero causes it to fail to load, "cannot find System.Buffers version 4.0.2.0 or one of its dependencies". What I think is going on here is that the DLLs required for all this Azure stuff are just incompatible with whatever DLLs are loaded by PowerShell in the first place, and there's just no working around it.  I couldn't use Entity Framework in a PowerShell cmdlet for either. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59258265/using-entity-framework-core-in-a-powershell-cmdlet

Comment: This seems so likely to be a dead end, or at least brittle - breaking at the next update - that I've decided to abandon the cmdlet idea and just build my own .EXE (as I did with the Entity Framework stuff). Appreciate the insight.